# Total record count in crystal report 2005

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, dataset

i am new to crystal report. i want to display total record count in header section of report. i have one group and record are divided according to that. In below sample next to Total Count it should show 3.

Sample report:

```
Total Count: "?"

Hospital : Mumbai               
    #   Name    

    1   abc 
    2   xyz                 

Hospital : Pune                         

    #   Name    

    1   abc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not that difficult, you have to create a new formula field, you just have to select from the functions->Summary->Count
And then put your formula field inside your header section, I attach a picture

[image]

Comment: I had tried same thing but i'm sure i have missed something while doing that. thankx for your help

Answer (score 0):

Right-Click on the number field and click on "Insert". Choose "Summary" and then choose "SUM" under "Calculate this Summary". As "Summary Location" choose the "Grand Total (Report Footer)" and click "OK". Then go in your designer and move the summary from the REport Footer to the Report Header.